# TypeError: property is not configurable, js engine: hermes

Tags: ios, react-native, babeljs, tailwind-css, react-native-hermes

spent ages on this error today and cannot figure it out at all.

It was working fine and then I installed [nativewind](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind)

Now, I keep getting the following errors after running `npm run ios`:

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). 
Module has not been registered as callable. 
Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): 
Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, 
RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.

A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an 
early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

My `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['nativewind/babel', 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 13'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "link": "react-native link"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.19.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/metro-config": "^5.1.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "postcode": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.36.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.8.8",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-draggable-grid": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.4.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "use-debounce": "^8.0.4",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-timeago": "^4.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried:

1. restarting my machine
2. `npm start -- --reset-cache`
3. `cd ios pod install`
4. uninstalling `nativewind` (even when uninstalled, the error now persists, so I can't get back to my working version beforehand)

Comment: This has to do with react-native-reanimated; my issue was using a custom Tab Bar with react-navigation. But the problem was caused by reanimated

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/4252